# Mocking `getAppState()` with Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my actions in my React / Redux application, and in one of my actions, I am using `getAppState()` to get the current state of Redux. The action has no parameters, and simply deconstructs state properties from the return of `getAppState()`

***actions/myFile/index.test.js***

```
it('should call myAction successfully', () => {
  const expected = [
    {
      type: MY_TYPE,
      payload: {
        ...mockPayload
      }
    }
  ];

  store.dispatch(myAction());
  expect(store.getActions().toEqual(expected));
});
```

***actions/myFile/index.js***

```
export const myAction = () => (dispatch, getAppState) => {
    const { myReducer: { reducerProp } } = getAppState();
    const { valOne, valTwo, valThree } = reducerProp;

    return myServiceCallPromise({ valOne, valTwo }, valThree)
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch(anotherAction());
        });
}
```

When trying to test my action with Jest, I'm getting an error stating:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reducerProp' of undefined
```

My question is HOW do I mock what the `getAppState()` func returns and use them in my test? I have googled once, saw the results and figured, why not go to StackOverflow and ask myself lol

Comment: As a side note: while you can give any name you want to a function parameter, that argument is normally referred to as `getState`, not `getAppState`.  I was very confused by what you meant at first, because of the unfamiliar name being used.

Comment: Correct! Sorry about that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm also assuming you are using `redux-thunk`).

You are going to need to configure your `store`:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const initialState = {
  myReducer: { reducerProp: 'something here' }
};

const store = mockStore(initialState)

// Your code down here...
```

See [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writingtests#example-1) for more info about how to use the store.